# How to define a variable and dynamically link to a URL in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to extend onto the 'blog tutorial' from cakephp and am having a little trouble with linking to a logged in user's homepage, which I created on a file called `view.ctp`.

I can link to most of my file path `http://localhost:8888/blogtest/users/view/` up until I need the 'id' to define which page to send someone too.

This is how I am linking to the page:

```
<a href="/blogtest/users/view/<?php ?>">go</a>
```

I know I need some logic within the `php` tags to tell the browser to retrieve the id of the current logged in user.

How would I got about doing this? Where would I create a variable?*

Does the var go in the `UsersController.php` or is it in the `User.php`? Any help is greatly appreciated!

UsersController php:

```
<?php

// app/Controller/UsersController.php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');



class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    // Allow users to register and logout.
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'logout');
    }

    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }

    public function view($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
    }

    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        }
    }

    public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
            );
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
            unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        }
    }

    public function delete($id = null) {
        // Prior to 2.5 use
        // $this->request->onlyAllow('post');

        $this->request->allowMethod('post');

        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->User->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to [the blog tutorial text](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html):

> The single instruction in the action uses set() to pass data from the
>   controller to the view (which we’ll create next). The line sets the
>   view variable called ‘posts’ equal to the return value of the
>   find('all') method of the Post model.

[It goes on here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#creating-post-views) and explains *exactly* what you want:

```
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
```

Honestly I have doubts you tried to read it at all. If you really did read this section again. [It is all there](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#creating-post-views) in great detail.

Comment: It really doesn't matter how *detailed* a doc is for me. Coming from a background of graphic design, I'm a pretty visual learner, I have to learn by doing something. I don't pick up logic as easily through reading. Thanks though.

Comment: Well, you have a serious problem then. Except flow charts and DB diagrams you won't find much to learn visually in the programming world. You could try UML. ;) From my experience here on Stackoverflow it is a very common problem for A LOT people to simply read documentation carefully. You need to learn to work with structured text information first. Also the documentation comes with plenty of example code to simply copy and paste for trial and error for the people who can't or won't read documentation. But IMHO it is crucial to understand the underlying concepts first.

Comment: I agree completely, and in a perfect world I would go out and find a class on it. But this world isn't perfect and I was brought into a project to help a fellow colleague at work and have a time limit of learning so i've written down what I would need to know how to do and have been focusing on learning that.

Comment: Do the online training then. http://training.cakephp.org/ You'll have somebody sharing his screen for 300min with you and a few other participants and you can ask questions and see what he's doing.

Comment: That's perfect, I'll shoot that link over to the CTO and try to get it paid for.

As for now, I guess I'll redo the blog tutorial, again. Try and pick up on what all is going on. Thanks!